# Why is second message sometimes not received?

Tags: erlang

I created a simple server to receive messages from a single client but when I send multiple messages at once, sometimes they are not received as I intended.
Here is the server code:

```erl
test() ->
    {ok, LSock} = gen_tcp:listen(7777, [binary, {active, true}, {packet, 0}, {reuseaddr, true}]),
    spawn(fun() -> acceptor(LSock) end).

loop() ->
    receive
        {tcp, Socket, Bin} ->
            io:format("Received: ~p~n", [binary_to_term(Bin)]),
            loop();
        {tcp_closed, Socket} ->
            io:format("Socket Closed~n"),
            exit(normal);
        {tcp_error, _} ->
            exit(normal);
        _ ->
            io:format("Unknown Message~n"),
            exit(normal)
    end.


acceptor(LSock) ->
    {ok, Sock} = gen_tcp:accept(LSock),
    io:format("Client Connected~n"),
    Pid = spawn(fun() -> loop() end),
    gen_tcp:controlling_process(Sock, Pid).
```

And the way I'm connecting to the server is through the Erlang shell as such:

```erl
{ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:connect("localhost", 7777, [binary, {packet, 0}, {active, true}]).`
```

But when I do `gen_tcp:send(Socket, term_to_binary(data1)),gen_tcp:send(Socket, term_to_binary(data3)).` many times in a row, most of the time it only shows "Received data1" but not "Received data3". For example, when I called that portion of code twice, I got:

```
Received: data1
Received: data3
Received: data1
```

Why is this happening? If I call each send one by one, it works as expected, but not if submit these two as a single "command".

**Note**: I've also tried waiting between connecting and sending because I read that there might be race conditions because of the `gen_tcp:controlling_process()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because TCP is a byte stream protocol, not a packet-based protocol. When you send two pieces of data at almost the same time, the OS can decide to combine them in a single TCP packet. (This saves on bandwidth, since each TCP packet has a 40 byte header in front of the data.)

So in the `loop` function, `Bin` contains both messages, one after another.
The `binary_to_term` converts the first one to a term, but it doesn't check whether that term occupied the entire binary, and so doesn't raise an error. You can try this in the shell:

```erlang
> A = <<(term_to_binary(data1))/binary, (term_to_binary(data3))/binary>>.
<<131,100,0,5,100,97,116,97,49,131,100,0,5,100,97,116,97,51>>
> binary_to_term(A).
data1
```

There are various things you can do about this:

- Use a packet-oriented protocol such as UDP instead of TCP. When using UDP, either you receive the exact data packet sent, or you receive nothing at all. Note that UDP doesn't provide some TCP features such as in-order delivery and retries on packet loss. If you need those, you'll have to implement them in your application. (In fact, that's what browser developers did when they invented [QUIC](https://blog.cloudflare.com/the-road-to-quic/), which is used to run HTTP/3 on top of UDP.)
- Introduce some kind of framing. For example, HTTP signals the end of the request header and the start of the request body with an empty line, and then the length of the request body is specified by the `Content-Length` header; after that many bytes, a new request starts.

  A simpler way is to add the length of the message at the beginning of each message - and Erlang provides built-in support for that! You currently use `{packet,0}` in both `gen_tcp:listen` and `gen_tcp:connect`, which explicitly turns off that feature. If you set both to `{packet,1}`, `{packet,2}` or `{packet,4}`, each message sent with `gen_tcp:send` will be prefixed with a length in 1, 2 or 4 bytes respectively, and each message you receive as `{tcp, Socket, Bin}` will be one whole message, the decoding and buffering having been handled by the Erlang runtime.
- Read one term at a time from the incoming data, and save incomplete data for later.

  This works because the data produced by `term_to_binary` in itself includes the length, so it's possible to find out where the next message starts. If you pass the `used` option to `binary_to_term`, you get the number of bytes "consumed", and thus where you need to start reading the next message. Continuing the above example, with `A` containing two messages:

  ```erlang
  > {Message, Used} = binary_to_term(A, [used]).  
  {data1,9}
  %% we get the first message, and we know that the next message starts 9 bytes in
  > <<_:Used/bytes, B/binary>> = A.
  <<131,100,0,5,100,97,116,97,49,131,100,0,5,100,97,116,97,51>>
  %% we skip over the specified amount of bytes, and store the rest in B
  > {Message2, Used2} = binary_to_term(B, [used]).
  {data3,9}
  %% we get the second message, and it also used 9 bytes
  > <<_:Used2/bytes, C/binary>> = B.              
  <<131,100,0,5,100,97,116,97,51>>
  %% we extract the rest of the binary
  > C.
  <<>>
  %% the remainder is empty, so we have read everything
  ```

  This is straight-forward when we get multiple entire messages in a single TCP packet, but it gets tricky when the opposite happens: a message is split across several TCP packets. In that case, we'll have to keep a buffer of data that we have received but doesn't add up to a complete term yet, and when we get more data, append that to the buffer and retry `binary_to_term`.

With all that said, if you control both the client and the server I'd recommend using `{packet,4}` - but it's important to understand why it works, and why it sometimes doesn't work without it.

---

There is a race condition related to `gen_tcp:controlling_process` in your code. Because you've specified `{active,true}` to `gen_tcp:listen`, any incoming data will be sent as messages to the current controlling process immediately. If you receive data between the calls to `gen_tcp:accept` and `gen_tcp:controlling_process`, that message will be sent to the wrong process. You can fix that by specifying `{active,false}` in `gen_tcp:listen`, and explicitly tell the child process that it can switch that back:

```erlang
acceptor(LSock) ->
    {ok, Sock} = gen_tcp:accept(LSock),
    io:format("Client Connected~n"),
    Pid = spawn(fun() -> pre_loop(Sock) end),
    gen_tcp:controlling_process(Sock, Pid),
    Pid ! controlling_process_changed.

pre_loop(Sock) ->
    receive
        controlling_process_changed ->
            inet:setopts(Sock, [{active, true}]),
            loop()
    end.

loop() ->
    %% no changes here
```